# Quando usar o plural de "mil"?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, número-gramatical, morfologia

Estou com uma dúvida na qual não consigo enxergar onde está o problema. Hoje, vindo ao trabalho, surgiu uma dúvida: Quando devemos pluralizar a escala **mil**? Por qual motivo não pluralizamos a escala quando estamos contando?

*Exemplo: um mil, dois mil, três mil, quatro mil... um milhão, dois milhões, três milhões, quatro milhões...*

Quando devemos, efetivamente, utilizar ***milhares*** ou ***mil*** e por quê?

Alguns exemplos:

> - "Desemprego cai e atinge **13 milhões** de pessoas" - *IBGE*
> - "**61 mil** pessoas foram assassinadas no Brasil em 2016" - *FBSP*
> - "**Milhares** se manifestam em Madri contra separação da Catalunha" - *O Tempo*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Milhares*** é plural de ***milhar:*** um milhar de casas, três milhares de casas. **Mil**, exceto em usos especiais (ver abaixo), é invariável: *mil casas, três mil casas.*

### Indicação de Quantidades

Para indicar quantidades exatas, é em princípio possível usar *mil* ou *milhar*, especialmente se a quantidade for um número certo de milhares:

> Recebemos um carregamento de dois mil isqueiros.
>
> Recebemos um carregamento de dois milhares de isqueiros.

Mas eu acharia estranho, mesmo não vendo incorreção nenhuma, “já vendemos dois milhares, trezentos e sessenta e oito bilhetes”; toda a gente diz “dois mil, trezentos e sessenta e oito”.

Isto é uma questão de estilo e preferência pessoal, mas na minha sensibilidade, *milhares* é mais usado em números redondos—*três milhares, vinte milhares*—do que em números como 378 milhares; e é mais usado ainda se a coisa quantificada vier em grupos de mil. Por exemplo, nos meus exemplos acima é possível imaginar duas caixas com mil isqueiros cada. Mas mesmo nestes caso, creio que existe uma preferência por *mil*, possivelmente por ser mais compacto e não precisar da preposição *de* (*dois mil isqueiros* vs. *dois milhares **de** isqueiros*).

Onde nós só podemos usar *milhares* é para exprimir muito vagamente um número muito elevado, como no teu último exemplo:

> Milhares se manifestam em Madri contra separação da Catalunha.

Aqui os manifestantes tanto poderiam ser 4 000, como 40 000, como 14 482. Não é possível esta vagueza com *mil*. Se disseres “mil manifestantes”, são mesmo 1 000. É possível é usar hiperbolicamente *milhares, mil* ou *mil e um* com o significado ‘muitos’:

> Depois arranjou mil (e uma) desculpas para não me ajudar.
>
> Depois arranjou milhares de desculpas para não me ajudar.

Para exprimir um valor aproximado, também é possível usar os dois, precedendo-os de *uns/umas:*

> Os manifestantes seriam apenas uns três mil.
>
> Os manifestantes seriam apenas uns três milhares.

Aqui estamos a falar, digamos, de 2 500 a 3 500 manifestantes.

Depois ainda há o uso poético de *mil* posposto ao nome da coisa quantificada, com o significado figurado ‘muitos’:

> Cidade maravilhosa, cheia de encantos mil.
>   [André Filho, *Cidade Maravilhosa*, 1935 (Wikipédia).](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hino_da_cidade_do_Rio_de_Janeiro)
>
> Abril, águas mil. (Provérbio; abril é em Portugal um mês de muitos aguaceiros.)

O que disse acerca de *milhar* aplica-se também a *dezena, vintena, centena*, etc. Estes numerais são designados *numerais cardinais especiais* ou *coletivos*; enquanto *mil, um, dois, trinta, duzentos e quatro*, etc. são *numerais cardinais comuns*.

### *Mil* especificativo

Nós podemos usar os numerais cardinais comuns, como mil (mas não os especiais, como *milhar*), para dizer coisas como:

> Abre o livro na página mil.
>
> No primeiro milénio muitos acreditaram que o mundo acabaria no ano mil.

Nestes exemplos o numeral não indica uma quantidade; antes serve, diz a Gramática da Gulbenkian (Lisboa, 2013, p. 930), “para especificar um exemplar único do tipo denotado pelo nome [“página” e “ano” nos meus exemplos], ou seja, para tornar o sintagma nominal de certo modo equivalente a um nome próprio”. Em nota de rodapé acrescenta que foi sugerido que nestas construções está implícita a palavra *número*—*página [número] mil*.

### Usos especiais de *mil*

Nestes casos *mil* é substantivo e admite plural: foram sugeridos *mis* (como em *funil, funis* e *vil, vis*) ou *miles* (como em *mal, males* e *cal, cales*). Vêr o [*Plural de mil* (Ciberdúvidas)](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/plural-de-mil/11651).
 Isto é válido para todos os numerais cardinais comuns, por isso eu começo com exemplos de outros números, que são mais familiares:

> Os teu setes confundem-se com uns, porque tu não fazes o tracinho horizontal nos setes.
>
> Grande vigarista: acrescentou um zero aos miles para os transformar em dez miles.

Aqui *mil* não se refere ao número em si, mas ao seu nome, nos meus exemplos, tal como representado graficamente.

Outro tipo de usos é:

> Estou com um azar: só me saem quatros e cincos; ainda não me saiu nenhum ás!
>
> Neste semestre tive dois oitos, um a Matemática, outro a Física. (Mau em Portugal, onde as notas são de zero a vinte.)

Aqui os números referem-se por metonímia a cartas de jogar com esse número e à classificação de oito valores. Numa escala de zero a mil é possível, em teoria, obter vários miles; ou mis.

Comment: O uso de "miles" é regionalismo do Rio Grande do Sul, onde pode ser usado para substituir "milhares": *miles de manifestantes*, *miles de desculpas* (mas nunca * *sete miles*). É certamente tomado de empréstimo ao espanhol platino, mas vai caindo em desuso.